# PRESTASHOP 8.1 - Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: prestashop

I have a problem with **PrestaShop 8.1**.

I have imported my product list into Prestashop as I usually do, using a file created in Excel or sublime text - encoded CVS (`ISO-8859-1 --from-code=UTF-8`) and everything is perfect.

But once I enter the product catalog and select a product to modify, I cannot. Any modification I make does not give me the option to save it, nor does it give me the option to add images, or modify price, or categories. (I can change it but the save and publish button is disabled)

This only happens with the products that I have exported, I have created a product manually and the same thing does not happen.

Made two new installations, both on localhost and on the server and the same thing happens.

The error is the following:

```
Uncaught error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: in main.bundle.js file
```

Image 1:
[image]

When you add these characters in the meta description `` <.,"'¡!¿?`´[]{}@=/%&#$| `` the error in *Image 1* appears.

Image 2:
[image]

##### Additional Information:

PrestaShop version: 8.1.1

PHP version: 8.2